# New Laptop Battery

Tags: windows-7, battery-life, battery

My laptop battery recently decided to kick the bucket, so I bought a replacement. I charged the replacement for approx 4 hours and assuming it was fully charged (only took my last batt 4 hours) unplugged and went on my way.

Later I started up my laptop and the battery was only a 11% charged. Since I didn't have my charger, I used it until it hibernated and then plugged it in when I got home. Now, after 24+ hours of charging, it won't charge further than 0% charge. I tried to calibrate the battery (by discharging and recharging) however each time the laptop shuts of after only 5 minutes.

Have I wrecked this battery somehow by discharging it after only a 11% charge, or is it just a bad battery?

Comment: Is it an NiCD battery?  Give us details on the batt, and the laptop.

Comment: Laptop is an Acer Aspire 8920G and battery is 8-cell Li-ion, 14.8V/5200mAh.

Comment: Have you checked you AC/DC power pack to ensure it's outputting the correct voltage?

Comment: I haven't since the laptop works fine plugged in, and the other battery will charge (only to about 1%) on it..

Comment: @john Is the Acer Aspire battery you bought the exact same one you had?

Comment: Yes, my last battery was an AS07B32 and the battery has "Replacement for AS07B32" written on it. The only difference is my original battery is 4800mAh and this one is 5200mAh. All the replacement batteries I found were 5200mAh. Couldn't find a 4800mAh.

Comment: Well, calibrating a Li-ion is pointless. They don't get memory buildup like the NiCDs did. Secondly, are you sure your power pack is ok? Did you try with another charger?

Comment: Well, I don't have another charger, however correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the charger be fine if it powers the laptop fine and charges the old battery fine? (I'm currently on the laptop without the battery)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, manufacturers typically want you to charge the batter for 10 to 12 hours, EVEN if the light says its charged.  While, yes, it doesn't have memory problems, something tells me a fresh battery has other issues that cause the OS to misjudge the capacity, this giving you weird readings.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. However I did charge the battery for over 24 hours after I plugged it in again and it still wouldn't hold more than a charge to power the laptop for 3-5 minutes. Also, I've been charging it through the laptop, not on an external charger.